# Does std::unordered_multimap's bucket only contain elements with equivalent keys

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

On www.CPlusPlus.com, it states the following for unordered_multimap,

> Elements with equivalent keys are grouped together in the same bucket and in such a way that an iterator (see equal_range) can iterate through all of them.

I know we cannot infer this from that statement, but I'd like to know if a given bucket **only** contains elements with the equivalent keys?

Comment: A trivial example would be a map with only one bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the only pertinent requirements:

> `[C++11: 23.2.5/5]:` Two values `k1` and `k2` of type `Key` are considered equivalent if the container’s `key_equal` function object returns true when passed those values. If `k1` and `k2` are equivalent, the hash function shall return the same value for both. *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 23.2.5/8]:` The elements of an unordered associative container are organized into buckets. Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket. *[..]*

There is nothing prohibiting *all* elements with key hash `a` and *all* elements with key hash `b` from being stored in the same bucket. It is up to the standard library implementation that you use as to whether or not this fact is used.

No standard wording exists to make this explicit; it's defined by omission.

Comment: One thing I've never understood about these *buckets* is `max_load_factor`. What if I set that to a low value, and then keep inserting `value_type`s with identical keys? Do they all end up in the same bucket? If so, that doesn't match description of `max_load_factor`. If not, it goes against the quote above. Or am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: @Praetorian: You keep inserting elements and it will keep adding new buckets and rehashing.  They'll just keep rehashing themselves into the same bucket.  That's allowed.  load_factor is merely the _average_ number of elements per bucket.

Comment: @MooingDuck I still don't get it, and [here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42e18b890144634d) an example that confuses me even more. Clearly, the bucket interface works, but how can I end up with 97 buckets, and still be able to retrieve all the values for a key, using a single bucket index?

Comment: @praetorian A typical `unordered_` implementation will create new buckets as its content size grows.  All of the elements can still end up in the same bucket due to anything from bad luck, a poor hashing function, or because all of the hashed values are the same (in your case).

Comment: @Yakk That makes a lot of sense. So bucket count increases with size to keep the load factor in check, but there's nothing preventing all elements from being dropped into the same bucket. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Yakk is correct. If you happen to have unordered container values with different keys located in the same bucket, it probably occurred due to the container load factor being dangerously high. In such cases the probability of a hash collision to occur is high, thus you should do a rehashing to stabilize it, like so : unorderedContainer.rehash(x) and you should specify x to be the number of buckets larger than those the container already occupies. The hash table will be reconstructed properly

Answer (score 2):

Elements with the same key will end up in the same bucket, but other elements may also end up in the same bucket.  You cannot infer that all elements in the same bucket have equivelent keys.

I don't think the spec says this explicitly, but the way the unordered_map works is that it uses the hash of the key to determine which bucket the element goes in.  Two keys can hash to the same value, which would mean both keys would be put into the same bucket.  However, two elements with the same key will have the same hash, and thus *always* be in the same bucket.  Additionally Since the number of buckets can be set in the constructor, then each bucket must therefore contain a range of keys, though the ranges will change as the number of buckets changes.

You could, have an unordered_multimap that attempted to use one bucket per 100 elements on average, which would be conforming (and rediculously silly), but if you had less than 100 elements it would be putting all of the elements into a single bucket.